# Minify/Combining JS Files

Tags: javascript, minify

I have around 6-7 javascript files that I want to minify and combine.  I have been minifying my javascript here: http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

I am having a little difficulty "combining" my javascript.  By combine, am I just copy and pasting all the javascript to one huge js file?  If I do this, I will end up with around 1000 lines of code and I have to figure out exact dependencies.  Is there an easy program online that can do this for me?  Also, do I have to combine scripts such as jquery with my scripts?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you eventually need to change something in this unique js, you will have big problems.

Comment: @Fel Yeah I have non-minified versions of all my scripts, but for site performance, I am combining everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the Closure Compiler from Google, that will combine JS files and minify them to a level of your choosing. It certainly saves a great deal of playing about with cutting & pasting which, as you probably know, can get very complicated.

Comment: Perfect solution.  Do you or anyone else know why my js would break when I do a minify on it?  Is it because of the minifier or my script?  I am confused because the closure compiler broke my js just like that site I provided above.

Comment: @yookd Where does it brake it?

Comment: @Aleadam After using the Closure Compiler, it points to the script that it outputs.  I minified my scripts one by one and found out which script was breaking it, but I have no idea why.  It points to line 1, but everything is in line 1.  Without minifying the JS, it works fine.

Comment: I have occasional problems with minifying as well, sometimes it is simple stuff like a missing semi-colon, others I haven't been able to get to the bottom of, so I move that code out to a separate file that doesn't get minified, then I can worry about it later (probably about March 2020). Some code definitely should not be minified, tinyMCE springs to mind, but that is pretty much shrunk anyway. Issues can occur with globals, the way to deal with these is well documented so I'll not go over it again here, but moving them to a separate file seems to do the job.

Comment: @yookd that's the problem with minified code. Debug line 1! Does JSLint give you any clue?

Comment: Check this(https://github.com/hkasera/minify) python script. It may help you. It stores detailed log files also. You can add this script as a git hook and save yourself from doing it manually everytime.

Answer (score 4):

I just use Notepad++ and the JSMin plugin. I would just copy them in the order in which you include them in your html files.

And no, I would not combine jsquery plugin with it. Keep them separate so you can update independently of them.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Check out PackScript.

http://danderson00.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/packscript-next-generation-build-for-web.html

It does all you need and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Check this python script.

http://github.com/hkasera/minify

It minifies js as well as css files too. It stores detailed log files and you can add this script as a git hook and save yourself from doing it manually everytime.

Hope it may help!